# jquery select element which doesn't has the active class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I want to make a animation when the user clicks on an element. Except if the element has the class 'active'.

```
<div class="collectionContainer">
            <div class="collectionName">SPRING SUMMER <br> 2012</div>
            <div class="collSex"><a href="#" id="collection1-man" class="active"> MAN </a></div>
            <div class="collSex"><a href="#" id="collection1-woman"> WOMAN </a></div>
        </div>
```

my jquery code

```
$('.collSex a').click(function(){
        $('.collSex a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        ...
        ...
    });
```

When an element has the class active I don't want to make the action/animation...

How should I do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.hasClass` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method:

```
$('.collSex a').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        $('.collSex a.active').andSelf().toggleClass('active');
        //...
    }
});
```

or use event delegation:

```
$('.collSex').on('click', 'a.active', function() {
    $('.collSex a.active').andSelf().toggleClass('active');
    //...
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked. It must be  
$('.collSex a').andSelf().toggleClass('active');

Otherwise it doesn't toggle the class

Comment: But that would add the `active` class to all other links as well... this way, it will remove it from the link with class `active` and add it to the current link.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.collSex a').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    ... 
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using jQuery `hasClass` method.

```
$('.collSex a').click(function(){ 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
         //Your code here.
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can take advantage of the **not** selector

```
$('collsex a:not(.active)').click(function(){ ....};
```

Comment: That would be evaluated only once when the page loads. The classes are changed during runtime.